# CLion C++ formatting

Tags: c++, formatting, format, code-formatting, clion

**Hey there I would like to know how I could achieve the following:**

I would like to format this piece of code (1. CLion Default, 2. what I want)

```
Mat<int, 4> m2({
                       Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5}),
                       Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5}),
                       Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5}),
                       Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5})
               });
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
Mat<int, 4> m2({
    Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5}),
    Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5}),
    Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5}),
    Vec<int, 4>({2, 3, 4, 5})
});
```

I couldn't figure out the right settings.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but currently you can not. We have similar [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8064) in tracker. Please, vote!